# How would humans mutate in an urban enviroment?

Tags: evolution, post-apocalypse

How would humans evolve in an urban environment? Allow me to give some more details.

- Specifically on a small island, roughly at 800 square miles in size. Excluding beaches, parks, and other such things, the entire island is covered in a dense city.
- This island averages at 20° Celcius to 8° depending on the season. The weather is usually calm, without natural disasters.
- This city is in ruins, and constantly falling apart. While plants have regrown, the concrete jungle still prevails.
- There is a rapid mutagen, in fine powder form, in the air. This mutagen has the ability to randomly alter large amounts of human DNA. This mutagen can spread if someone eats the flesh of an animal who has come in contact with this mutagen. It will lose it's mutating property when in contact with water.
- Mutations start off small (and random), but grow stronger over 'infected' populations. The first generation may only have small genetic abnormalities, but 6 generations in and one can begin to see drastic deviations between human and 'infected'. Animals are also effected by this.
- Natural selection still applies, so harmful traits likely won't spread. Consider it rapid evolution.
- The mutagen originates (and is contantly being expelled from) a large factory building in the northeast. Mutations will be more intense the closer they are to this.

-Mutated forms of urban wildlife (Mice, roaches, raccoons) and ex-domestic animals (Dogs, Cats, perhaps even pet birds) are the fauna of the area. Humans are also in conflict with one another, which may influence evolution.

**There are two areas that I specifically want to focus on.**

- The surface city itself, with the overgrown flora mixing with city ruins to create a dense, diverse landscape. This area also has the most mutagen in the air (and collected on the ground).
- An underground settlement, founded after three generations. The settlement lays in a large, previously abandoned mine, filled with water. These people survive by fishing and mushroom farming.

It would have been 340 years since mutations began. Assume no contact with the outside world. Please, ask any questions you have. There is quite a bit of hand-waving with things, so don't feel concerned about getting things down to hard-science if you don't want to.

Comment: Do you have something against [Anders Cel**s**ius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Celsius) personally, or is it all Swedes?

Comment: This question, in one sentence, is: "What is the outcome of my completely random process?" This can not be answered with anything at all but a personal opinion. The outcome of an evolution is determined by the selection process, not the mutation process. Evolution is subtractive. What is the natural predator (it says natural selection applies) hunting your urban humans?

Comment: "*This mutagen has the ability to randomly alter large amounts of human DNA*" suggests that your inhabitants will suffer from many forms of cancer.

Comment: @VogonPoet My intention was not to ask for a predication on random processes, but what kind of trends may be established. With natural selection still existing, I felt humans might adapt into specific niches. As for predators, I feel the biggest threat would be other humans. With the environment having no real wild areas, variations of urban wildlife and descendants of human domestic pets would be the most common. I can see packs of mutated dogs being a noticeable threat however.

Comment: Whatever mutations may have allowed them to not starve in the first few months of being cut off from the rest of the world. Cities don't make food, definitely nowhere near enough to maintain their populations.

Comment: If the mutagen loses potency when it contacts water, how does it work on water-based life?

Comment: What kind of mutations?  Epigenetic?  Sentence/word swap? Shuffle of amino acids along a span? Each of those has wildly different levels of affects. Also If a person has to eat infected, how the heck does it survive the digestive system? If people make stew out of infected plants/animals does that not neutralize the mutagen?

Comment: Humans already have mutated to adapt to an urban environment. Having one copy of the Tay-Sachs disease gene, prevalent in several populations, most notably Ashkenazi Jews, is believed to protect against tuberculosis, formerly a common urban disease. (Having two copies generally is fatal.)

Comment: Uh… what? How is Asking "How would humans mutate in an urban environment" different from Asking "How might we mutate in future"?

Comment: @JamesFaix So long as the life remains in water, it is completely unchanged. Fish, underwater plants, and other such life are safe from the mutagen.

Comment: @GaultDrakkor The mutations themselves are a shuffling of amino acids. I will admit, despite my researching into how mutations work I still find much of it to be out of my current knowledge. I’ve changed a few things about this mutagen since seeing Starfish Prime’s answer however, nanosystems, specifically nanomachines once designed for medicinal purposes, work much better than my previously planned mutating pollen-comparable substance.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin This is intended more for how humans would mutate in a completely different setting than what we would adapt for without the same conditions. I imagine a non-post apocalyptical world without this mutagen would evolve much differently.

Comment: @Preott In that case, why not provide more matter and less art with which to work?

Why not rely on the hand-waving, instead of feeling concerned about science?

Your mutagen seems to matter first and most. Can you specify how it loses power to water? A splash on the skin, gallons ingested or ounces injected? 

Doesn't six generations changing much rely on the mutagen? Isn't 340 years about 17 generations?

How do humans in conflict influence evolution?

Your two foci help how?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Natural selection still applies, so harmful traits likely won't spread. Consider it rapid evolution.

Most mutations in any population are either neutral, or mildly deleterious. Humans are intelligent and adaptable and can overcome quite significant hinderances, especially if they are able to form a functional society.

> Specifically on a small island, roughly at 800 square miles in size. Excluding beaches, parks, and other such things, the entire island is covered in a dense city.

It is going to be awkward to generate enough food to keep a sizeable population fed... ploughing concrete is challenging, after all. This suggests that population sizes will be relatively small, which in turn suggests that [genetic drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_drift) could conceivably fix traits that are negative (but not *too* negative) over the span of just a few generations.

Natural selection isn't magical.

> There is a rapid mutagen, in fine powder form, in the air. This mutagen has the ability to randomly alter large amounts of human DNA.

Most people are just going to die of cancer, or organ malfunction, or some really weird multi-system failure. Mutation just doesn't work like it does in cartoons, you see.

If the original population was large enough, and there was a sufficient supply of long-life food, it might be possible that some people could survive the initial cancer plague, but if the mutagen is still present in the environment then the odds are that it will simply kill a big chunk of each generation until everyone is dead.

As such, the most valuable mutation that anyone might get is a resistance to the mutagen, because that's really the only way to survive over the long term.

> It would have been 340 years since mutations began

That's not actually very long when talking about heritable human mutations. Remember that bacteria and viruses mutate in interesting ways because they replicate in enormous numbers and over very short timescales which means that huge numbers of different mutations can be tried in parallel, and valuable changes can potentially dominate quite rapidly.

Humans reproduce comparatively slowly, so there's only so many generations you can squeeze into a mere 340 years, and there can only be a limited number of people at any one time because of their material demands. With a coronavirus infection, a single human will have millions or even [*billions* of active viral particles](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.11.16.20232009v1) in them, each one potentially testing a novel mutation. Spread that across billions of people, with [single virion "generation" being about 7-36 hours and forming hundreds of offspring](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7224694/), you can see that merely genetic evolution in humans just can't compete. All of our most dramatic changes over the last few tens of millenia have been social and technological ones. Sure, a lot of us have some minimal resistance to the plague, but is that really the sort of mutation you were hoping for?

---

What you really want, I suspect, is *not* some kind of random genome-scrambler that kills everyone with tumors that grow tumors or surprise whole-body necrolysis.

Evolution isn't goal-focussed, and mass-mutation isn't a great way to drive evolution unless the source population is massive and reproduces quickly and even then it seems likely that everything will just die if the mutation rate is too high.

Instead what you need is something that's less actively destructive and more goal oriented. The traditional avenue for this sort of thing might be "nanobots", which are things that might have some basic drive to improve stuff rather than cause turbo-leukemia. Given some basic notion of host fitness, medical nanomechanisms could be imagined that are equipped with an initial suite of improvements but are capable of accepting firmware upgrades from other nanomechanisms and attempting to randomly modify some of the upgrades in the hopes of generating something good.

What you have, then, is a large population of rapidly reproducing nanosystems (which might even be biological in origin... suites of engineered viruses, or bacteria, or fungi, or intracellular parasites or whatever else) which are subject to evolutionary pressures and humans which merely host them, and are affected by the changing set of modification programs the nanosystems are currently expressing.

> How would humans evolve in an urban enviroment?

Ultimately, you're absolutely free to handwave in literally anything. The environment is complex and potentially challenging in many different ways... although I can't see any practical route to laser eye beams, psychic powers or generating intense magnetic fields, there's room enough for you to bring in [patagia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patagium)... handy for gliding flight in vertical environments.

Comment: The mutagen will mutate to be less dangerous.   Those that don't kill off their hosts.

Comment: @Mary that's assuming that the mutagen is a self-replicating life form, while the original question indicates that it is a manufactured agent of some sort. The nanobots that Starfish Prime suggested would also be unlikely to mutate into a benign form... although whatever computer is controlling their manufacture might refine the template over time.

Comment: Nanomachines? My original planning was a heavily modified type of flower, that releases the mutagen as a pollen (initially, such pollen was to be turned into a variety of more controlled products, such as medicine to regrow a lost limb over 6 months.) However, nanomachines would be a better choice for avoiding complete extermination of the population. Thank you, I didn't even consider nanomachines before. They work much better.

Comment: If I ever start a death metal band, I'm gonna name it Surprise Whole-Body Necrolysis.

Answer (score 8):

**You would select for organisms resistant to mutation.**

Think of computer code.  Each Roomba is running its code, doing its Roomba thing.  Now you randomly alter segments of code.  It is remotely possible that you might improve your Roomba.  More likely if it does something it will do something that breaks the Roomba or makes it hang or get caught in subroutines or otherwise not vacuum up all the cat fur.

This is how it is with mutations.  A random change will probably be neutral or hurt the organism.

If you have a Roomba that does well despite this maybe it is resistant to your random alterations.  An organsim that does well in an environment full of mutagen could be resistant to the mutagen.  For example a mutagen that binds nucleic acid.  An organism that had great excesses of nonfunctional nucleic acid might bind up the mutagen in the nonfunctional RNA.  An organism with robust mutation repair could fix the mutation.

Those things are cool from a biology standpoint because the mechanisms used to resist and correct mutation are interesting.  From the standpoint of gripping fiction, I am not sure your postapocalyptic fiction readers will be digging a strain of kudzu that produces large quantities of intracellular noncoding RNA.

--
**High incidence of chronic cancer?**

A pretty cool approach to ambient mutagens is a high incidence of chronic cancers.  I think this is what they were showing in the Mad Max remake.  I think those pale warriors who needed blood transfusions had low grade lymphomas and that is why their necks were lumpy.  The older ones were lumpier.  Chronic cancers could be the stuff of postapocalyptic fiction.

Comment: If a group of people developed a resistance to the mutagen, I could see them leveraging that. Perhaps in combination with dominating the fish trade (fish/other sea creatures are not mutated due to the mutagen's inability to deal with water), we could see an upper class of mutants emerge. Very good to consider, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

## Getting Around

Urban environments are much like mountains, and so these humans would likely have mountain-dweller adaptations. Specifically they would likely have thick strong nails to grip onto the stone. Their feet will also adapt for gripping, both to hold on stone and to grab vines or ropes

## Staying Healthy

There won't be much food on this island, and so they'll need ways to cut down their nutritional requirements. One way to do this is to reduce their size. They will also be much more likely to encounter food while climbing, where it'll be harder to grab. Therefore they'd benefit from some sort of oral adaptations, such as a long tongue, to snap up food from the face of a building. Finally, they will need to resist the mutagen, as it will be extremely hazardous to their health due to the random mutations

Answer (score 3):

## A lot

Accelerating mutations is still not the same as determining the outcome of mutations. By distributing a mutagenic accelerant into the food supply your mutations will still be a completely random stochastic process (you did state as much), so there is no way to predict the outcome from mutation rate alone. Therefore, the evolution-based answer to "How will they mutate" can only be answered as "They will mutate a lot."

### What determines my final outcome then?

Selection is the only way to improve the chances of reaching some desired end arrangement. Evolution is a subtractive process that has two necessary components: Permanent random alteration of the original plan multiple times, then removing the unfavorable plans from the gene pool. Your world seems to have covered the first part: altering the plans for a "normal" human, but there seems to be no part of your story which removes the unfavorable plan.

The question states that "Natural selection still applies, so harmful traits likely won't spread." But what in your story is doing the natural selection? You have not described what your mutants' predators are. Is this city filled with mutant bears and lions? A mutated virus? The form of a human which survives (if any do at all) will be determined entirely by whatever apex predator or contagion or force is doing the selection.

**What is the result of my random process?**

That is the question being asked.

- Mutations are random:

> This mutagen has the ability to randomly alter large amounts of human DNA

- The predator is not even mentioned in the query

Therefore, you will need to handwave a great deal to assume humans here won't simply become extinct. So, let's do that, and assume some humans survive and remain fertile. The hand of trivially deleterious mutations has been waved.

That point aside, every answer is automatically correct. Will they evolve wings? Of course they will! The mutation was random, and nothing at all is doing any selection. Will they become amphibious? Most assuredly they will, because the mutation is random, and selection is whatever you want it to be. Will they gain ultra-violet vision? Yes, certainly; in this world, that random gene will happen (it's statistics, after all), and the selections will, by the mighty waved hand, not eat that girl and her siblings.

## Every answer is correct. Make them look how you want them to look

Comment: I've seen several requests for me to detail a predator/predators, so I will edit my question to include that. However, other than mutated variants of humans and urban wildlife/ex-domestic animals, there were no other animals present on the island. Right now, I see mutated humans and packs of hounds being the two largest threats.

Comment: That's fine but *something* has to be selecting which mutations survive and which ones die off. We didn't see anything doing that in your story, so how can we possibly say what mutations will survive? It's whatever you want as this is written.

Answer (score 2):

### You need a remarkable mutagen to avoid too high a mutational load

Suppose the average person picks up two harmful mutations each generation.  Selection flushes out the worst ... but the next generation still inherits the next-to-worst.  Just so, over time, the population becomes unable to carry on.  There are some defenses possible to this - most interestingly, a limited lifespan - but it won't deliver the vibrant, powerful evolution you are looking for.

Instead, give your "mutagen" a specific mechanism.  Perhaps it incorporates to one or a few adeno-associated virus integration sites, or uses Cas/CRISPR to target specific genes of interest.  Each time the person is exposed, it does something really involved and interesting, like splicing together exons from different genes to make a random fusion protein that gets reverse transcribed.  And *when the infection happens*, unless the person is truly virgin to the mutagen, it is going to *replace* a former mutation at one of these limited sites.

All that isn't really enough to make your mutants interesting, except on very rare occasions.  It might be better if there were some sort of simulation database or library of engineered constructs the mutagen is somehow drawing on (perhaps as simple as a range of template sequences in the fallout or in viruses in local plant life).  Ultimately you want your mutants to come out looking like somebody's science experiment, which means somebody had to have done the experiment.